# VSCode + Remote - SSH + VS Code Debugger for Firefox, How?

Tags: firefox, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

So, I'm trying to get the [vscode-firefox-debug](https://github.com/firefox-devtools/vscode-firefox-debug) to play.

It, `vscode-firefox-debug`, claims to be compatible with `vscode remote`.

**How do I configure this thing, to work with my remote?**

All my development is done on a remote headless server, running Slackware64 14.2

Let's call that box `www.example.com`.

My local box is a `Windows 8.1 x64 Pro` with:

`Firefox 69.0.1 (64-bit)`

```
Visual Studio Code
Version: 1.38.1 (system setup)
Commit: b37e54c98e1a74ba89e03073e5a3761284e3ffb0
Date: 2019-09-11T13:35:15.005Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 6.3.9600
```

I run firefox with `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -start-debugger-server`

I've got the `Remote-SSH` and friends setup, and working nicely with [vscode-php-debug](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug) and `XDebug`.

Adding to `launch.json` on remote server. I got a few variations I've tried:

**First try**

```
    {
      "name": "Launch localhost",
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "reAttach": true,
      "url": "http://localhost/index.html",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
```

[image: First launch config]

**Second try**

```
    {
      "name": "Attach localhost",
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "attach",
      "url": "http://localhost/index.html",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
```

[image: First attach config]

**Third try**

```
    {
      "name": "Launch index.html",
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "reAttach": true,
      "port": 6000,
      "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html",
      "url": "https://www.example.com/index.html",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
```

And I get a **Notification** in debug console, saying:

```
Firefox can't open a file in a remote workspace
```

**Last try**

```
    {
      "name": "Attach index.html",
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 6000,
      "url": "https://www.example.com/",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
```

[image: Another failed attempt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the link to help you:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug

Example to run on server to start manually xdebug while debug by SSH the file on local VS code IDE is:

```
$ php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 -dxdebug.remote_connect_back=1 /var/www/html/teste.php
```